# Jquery seesaw effect

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to do a seasaw effect with Jquery, but need some help with which plugin to use. I want the bar to go up and down and the box on the top to move with it. here is my code on JsFiddler: http://jsfiddle.net/semantic/LscQd/4/

Thanks

Comment: what do you mean up and down? do you have any similar examples you can point us to online?

Comment: I searched for it but coundn't found one, have a look here, something like this http://www.kzero.co.uk/blog/what-marketers-learned-in-2007-no-5-the-media-loves-second-life-the-media-hates-second-life/

when one side goes down, then box goes down with it aswell, and the same effect for the other side aswell. thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using the [jQuery Rotate plugin](http://code.google.com/p/jqueryrotate/), I was able to get the teeter-totter effect with an interval and a timeout:

```
setInterval(function(){
    $(".bar").rotate({animateTo:15});
    $(".box").animate({left:284},1000);
    setTimeout(function(){
        $(".bar").rotate({animateTo:-15});
        $(".box").animate({left:0},1000);        
    }, 1000);
}, 2500);​
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LscQd/10/

Comment: That's more like it. thanks Jonathan, nearly there, but now only need to move the box now.

Comment: @Eager4knowledge What do you mean, *move the box*? You want it to slide to the other side, and then back? If so, check my latest update.

Answer (score 2):

Quick attempt, not great I know but should be useful as a starting point. Uses css transforms to rotate seesaw between -30 and 30 degrees. Hope it helps

http://jsfiddle.net/czAHU/1/

edit: animating the bar instead looks much better than the whole wrapper. in all honesty though i didnt expect it to move the box too, so i might be a bit more cautious about it...
http://jsfiddle.net/czAHU/2/

Comment: Thanks Jorden, yes this is great as a starting point. I'll play around with it. lets see how it goes.